# How to do Pandas like mapping in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mapping, tensor

Suppose I have a 2-D Tensor as given below:

```
5645  0  0.5
5645  1  0.7
4125  1  0.1
7816  0  0.3
5645  1  0.0
```

I want to perform an operation on this tensor and create a new 1-D tensor as described below:

- The unique values of the first row will have same values in the output 1-D tensor.
- For each unique value in first column, I want to calculate a ratio, given as:

  sum of 1's in the second column for that unique value in first column / sum of values in third column corresponding to the 1's in second column.

For example: Consider the unique value 5645

```
5645  0  0.5
5645  1  0.7
5645  1  0.0
```

the output should be:

```
5645  0  0.5  2/0.7
5645  1  0.7  2/0.7
5645  1  0.0  2/0.7
```

And the final output should be:

```
5645  0  0.5  2/0.7
5645  1  0.7  2/0.7
4125  1  0.1  1/0.1
7816  0  0.3  0/0.3
5645  1  0.0  2/0.7
```

How to implement this in tensorflow?

Comment: I know you want a tensorflow solution, not a pandas but, why not do this with pandas?

Comment: Because it's required in the process of loss determination...the variables in computation graphs are empty until a session is run. Pandas won't work while defining the computation graph.

Comment: @ShivamChaudhary: Couple of Points: 

1. I see that even Output Tensor you specified is a 2-Dimensional. Can you please clarify about that?

2. Also, can you please clarify about the point, "The unique values of the first row will have same values in the output 1-D tensor."